# How to do count(distinct) for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

This does not work:

```
select count(distinct colA, colB) from mytable
```

I know I can simply solve this by making a double select.

```
select count(*) from (
    select distinct colA, colB from mytable
)
```

Is there anyway I can do this without having to do the sub-select?

Comment: Keep the subquery solution.

Comment: What is wrong with a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] Just use a sub-query.

---

If you are trying to use concatenation then you need to ensure that you delimit the terms with a string that is never going to appear in the values otherwise you will find non-distinct terms grouped together.

For example: if you have a two numeric column then using `COUNT(DISTINCT col1 || col2)` will group together `1||23` and `12||3` and count them as one group.

You could use `COUNT(DISTINCT col1 || '-' || col2)` but if the columns are string values and you have `'ab-'||'-'||'c'` and `'ab'||'-'||'-c'` then, once again, they would be identical once concatenated.

The simplest method is to use a sub-query.

If you can't do that then you can combine columns via string-concatenation but you need to analyse the contents of the column and pick a delimiter that does not appear in your strings otherwise your results might be erroneous. Even better is to ensure that the delimiter character will never be in the sub-string with check constraints.

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytable__col1__chk CHECK (col1 NOT LIKE '%¬%');
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytable__col2__chk CHECK (col2 NOT LIKE '%¬%');
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1 || '¬' || col2)
FROM   mytable;
```

Comment: Also, I suppose the subquery performance will be much better than the concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Subquery is standard solution which I recommend too. Concatenation-based solutions, except they are error-prone if dangerous character occurs, might be also worse in performance.

Note: in case you collected obscure solutions how to avoid subquery, window function usage is also possible here (**Not to be used in production** - your code reviewers won't praise you for it):

```sql
select distinct count(*) over ()
from my_table
group by colA, colB
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can (ab)use window functions and limit clause. These are evaluated after grouping. So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM t
GROUP BY col_a, col_b
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate them.

```
Select count(distinct colA ||'-'|| colB) from mytable;
```

Comment: well I know the Concatenate method, so now I am ashames I did not think of it myself :D Thank!

Comment: Will count ('AB', 'C') and ('A', 'BC') as one distinct combination.

Comment: Now it won't; thank you, @jarlh.

Comment: Now ('A-', 'B') and ('A', '-B') are both counted as ('A--B').

Comment: Oh well, if there's really such a data that nothing of suggested simple options helps, then subquery it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid sub-selects at all costs, one variant would be to concatenate them as such:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT concat(colA, colB)) FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Will count ('AB', 'C') and ('A', 'BC') as one distinct combination.

Answer (score 0):

*NB: The answer is for SQLite*

There's another option using JSON:

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT json_object('colA', colA, 'colB', colB))
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL you could simply use row values for this, e.g., `SELECT count(DISTINCT (colA, colB)) FROM mytable;`, but SQLite limits the usage of row values for some reason -- https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html. `json_object()` can be used as a substitution where you'd normally use a row value.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the tags for this question -- I thought it was for SQLite as I've been searching for SQLite options.