# Counting multiple columns distinct values grouped

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been trying to get this done, but I don't see how I can do this with [CASE WHEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query). Specifically, I'm grouping by `id` and I need to count every distinct value for each column (I'm not looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471250/counting-distinct-over-multiple-columns) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69836393/how-to-do-countdistinct-for-multiple-columns), even if it seems to be the same question). For example, I have this data:

```
ID Var_A Var_B
1  A      2022-01
1  B      2022-01
1  C      2022-01
2  A      2022-01
2  A      2022-02
2  Z      2022-03
2  Z      2022-01
```

Expected output

```
ID N_Var_A Var_B
1  3       1
2  2       4
```

You can see that I'm looking for the number of distinct values in each column for each id. I have been trying with:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(Var_A), COUNT(Var_B)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

Without success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below instead

```
select ID, 
  count(distinct Var_A) N_Var_A,
  count(distinct Var_B) N_Var_B
from your_table
group by ID
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]