# "Operational Error: row value misused" error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm getting an error from an sqlite3 query for which I can't find the reason.

```
CREATE TABLE professors (
    firstname            text,
    lastname             text,
    university_shortname text
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(firstname, lastname)) FROM professors;
```

Error:

> OperationalError: row value misused

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69836393/4611565) help ?

Answer (score 1):

[`COUNT()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count) aggregate function takes only 1 argument and that argument can't be a [row value](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) like `(firstname, lastname)`.

A workaround for your requirement would be the use of [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions) window function:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY firstname, lastname) AS distinct_count
FROM professors
ORDER BY distinct_count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3ue1bObb).

Note that the above query will count all the distinct combinations of  `firstname` and `lastname`, even the ones where one or both columns are `null`.